# Discord.py, client = discord.CLient() problem

Tags: discord.py

I cant know why my code doesn't print, there's no error in the code and interpreter seems normal, this doesn't print anything

here's code(some imports aren't being used because i deleted the code):

```
import asyncio
import os
import discord
import youtube_dl

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.utils import get
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv("TOKEN")
GUILD = os.getenv("GUILD")

intents = discord.Intents.all()  # is not being used
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents, case_insensitive=False)  # is not being used
discordVersion = discord.__version__
discordVersionInfo = discord.version_info


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.name == GUILD, client.guilds)

    print(
        f'{client.user} bot se conectou\n'
        f'{guild.name}( id: {guild.id})')

    members = '\n - '.join([member.name for member in guild.members])
    print(f'Guild Members:\n - {members}'
          f'\n The discord version is: {discordVersion}'
          f'\n The discord version info is: {discordVersionInfo}')

    print(
        f'{client.user} bot se conectou\n')

    client.run(TOKEN)
```

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ilQF.png)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dN9nz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtDgF.png)
Tried to make the bot run normally and anything happens

Comment: You have two "classes" of a bot. Either remove `bot` or `client`

Answer (score 0):

Decide if you want to use `bot` or `client` you can't use both at the same time. Also correct your formatting. The `client.run(token)` should be called outside of the `on_ready()` event.

Comment: How can I put client.run(token) outside on_ready (new at Python)

Comment: Delete the spaces in front of it.